# Show many action from different controllers in one view Symfony

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig, render

Im new to Symfony and I'm wondering if that idea could be done with Symfony2.

I need to create like a Dashboard, where many charts are shown. Every chart has its data from a Model, but everything should be shown in one template.

The problem comes when I try to call different actions from the same view, as every action needs a route, so I thought to create a controller action that calls to all the other actions, and render it within one method.

Is that idea affordable? Is there any other best practice to do that?

The view should be something like that:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div id="cabecera">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
</div>

<div id="contenido">
    {% block contenido %}{% endblock %}
</div> 
<div id="anonym_users">
    {% block anonym_users %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<div id="registered_users">
    {% block registered_users %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<div id="check_ins">
    {% block check_ins %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="pie">
    <hr/>
    <div align="center">- footer -</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Where every block would be a different view with data from different Model/Controllers.

Thanks a lot in advance, and sorry if that's a really newbie question, that's what I am.

Comment: What about AJAX to render every chart with its own route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using fragments: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework

You render a controller by its logical path like:

```
{{ render(controller('Bundle:controller:action')) }}
```

You can do this with as many controller actions as you need.

A view precautions however, avoid using controller fragments that perform significant tasks, since users may be forced to wait for many number crunching views to appear when they only need to see one.

Additionally, avoid placing any forms in the fragments (its a form handling/validation nightmare).  Make each fragments kind of like a sub-dashboard where users can select an action where they are taken to a dedicated form.

Edit:

Regarding your current code, in Twig, blocks can only be populated by the template that extend the originator of the blocks, thats only one template or the template further down the chain.  You can't 'include' a template can expect it to have access to the includer's blocks